# Smash up question

Tags: smash-up

well 
got in one base Game guru card a 3 power minion (ongoing this minion is not effected by other player's abilitis )
and in another base got a 4 power minion 
and my wife play's Bear Hug action {Each of other player destroys his or her minion with the least power (owner chooses in case of tiess)}.
what happend there ? 
and what mean in case of tie ?
 plz help us !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by the wordings you gave, Bear Hug select the 3 power minion to destroy it since there is no tie (ie: two minions sharing the same lowest power).
Since the minion is not affected by the effect, it is not destroyed.

Comment: and why not destroy the next minion in line? in this case the 4 power minion. ??? the 3 power minion has the no effect ability...ok but why not destroy the other one and instead cancel the action?! why is this the correct thing to do? please comment